# HttpResponse content type for csv and other extentions doesn't work in firefox but works in Chrome and IE

Tags: python, django, content-type, httpresponse

I am using PYTHON+DJANGO to implement a file sharing system. When a user attempts to download a file it works well in Chrome and IE but not Firefox, Firefox returns part of the file name and no extension if it does not recognize the extension (e.g. .pl and .csv)

View

```
filename = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, entry.myfile.url)
wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename,'rb'))
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/octet-stream')
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + entry.name
```

I tried content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filename) but this didn't solve the problem
I also tried replacing any spaces within the filename with periods, that did work! But I'm a sure there is a clean solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Answer to an old question, I know, but the actual issue is that you didn't enclose the filename with double quotes (and it has to be double, not single). IE and Chrome will read until the end of the line, but Firefox will read until the first space and stop.

So just change `response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=" + entry.name` to `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"'%(entry.name)` and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `django.views.static`:

```
import mimetypes
import os
import stat
from django.http import HttpResponse

statobj = os.stat(fullpath)
mimetype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
mimetype = mimetype or 'application/octet-stream'

with open(fullpath, 'rb') as f:
    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), mimetype=mimetype)

if stat.S_ISREG(statobj.st_mode):
    response["Content-Length"] = statobj.st_size
if encoding:
    response["Content-Encoding"] = encoding
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=%s'%os.path.basename(fullpath)
return response
```

Comment: This has the same workaround as mine (replacing spaces with periods), since at download the spaces are replaced with underscores. I am trying to allow the files to be downloaded without changing their names. But thank you for your help :)